# how can i automate my sentiment analysis in python

Tags: python, automation, sentiment-analysis

I am done predicting my sentiment analysis using real-time tweets from twitter but I need to automate it so I don't need to run it again at every interval.

How can i go about this

Kindly assist

Comment: `celery for python` create a schedule tasks to your function to run automatic every few interval

Comment: how can i create schedule task to my function to run automatically every few interval???...can you share a sample script to achieve this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) and [tweepy](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) to schedule your job; or use [streaming with tweepy](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html) standalone without necessity of scheduling.

**With using `schedule`, based on the example of `schedule`'s pypi homepage:**

```py
import schedule

def job():
    print("I'm working...")
    # do you work here

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

To mention, you can call functions or methods in `job()`. You don't have to write all your code there.

Comment: how can i create schedule task to my function to run automatically every few interval???

Comment: Thanks alot emremrah...I actually just completed a script on sentiment analysis to spool tweets from twitter and also analysed the script to predict the sentiments but I just applied the schedule function and its repeating same tweets over again as regards just automatically spooling tweets and saving it in a csv file....kindly assist

Comment: As far as I understand you have another problem that the script gets same tweets every time, right? If so, know that ids in twitter are incremental, so consider using `since_id` attribute of tweepy. It gets the tweets only that have greater ID than `since_id` (so it gets more recent tweets only).

Comment: Also, even if my answer didn't solve your problem completely, an upvote would be appreciated too :)

Comment: thanks alot...I just gave an upvote and I also just sent you a dm on twitter